# angularjs .then() doesn't work (then is not a function)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, factory

I have a little problem developing a simple GUI for a game idea using AngularJS (v1.3.15) and Angular-Route.
Anyway, for the registration, i want to pre-check the availability for the username while being typed. I set up a $watch, call the factory service to get an $http.post answer, but in my controller, I get the error "*fwMainService.checkUsernameAvailability(...).then is not a function*".
I triple checked every spelling, the syntax and logic (btw I'm new to Angular).
Every other factory function is working as it is supposed to.

Is it because checkUsernameAvailability() should return a promise, not a string?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

My Factory:

```
"use strict";

fwApp.factory('fwMainService', function ($http) {

var mFac = {};

mFac.checkUsernameAvailability = function (username) {
    if(username != '') {
        if(username.length >= 3) {
            $http.post('api/user/usernameInUse.php', {newUser: username})
            /* returns '1' if in use, '0' if free */
            .success(function (res) {
                if(res == '1') { // Username in use
                    return 'In Use!';
                } else if(res == '0') {
                    return 'Free!';
                }
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                console.log("username check error: ", error);
            });
        } else {
            return 'Username too short!';
        }
    } else {
        return ''; // if empty, do not check
    }
};

[...]

// Public API
return {
    checkUsernameAvailability: function (username) {
        return mFac.checkUsernameAvailability(username);
},
[...]
```

My Controller:

```
"use strict";    

fwApp.controller('IndexCtrl', 
         ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$location', 'fwMainService', 
function ( $scope,   $http,   $timeout,   $location,   fwMainService) {

/* username input field model = newUser.username */
$scope.$watch("newUser.username", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if(angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)) {
        return;
    }
    fwMainService.checkUsernameAvailability(newValue).then(function (res) {
        console.log("return", res.data);
        $scope.newUserMsg = res.data; // Setting infobox to "Free!" or "In Use!"
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("username check Error:", error);
    });

});

[...]
```

Edit #1: I added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyrm/71kz617g/6/
Maybe someone gets it working...

Comment: Try this  return checkUsernameAvailability(username);

Comment: in your factory replace 
return mFac.checkUsernameAvailability(username); by return checkUsernameAvailability(username); (i am not sure of this solution but you can try)

Comment: Negative, i get _Error: checkUsernameAvailability is not defined_, thx though

Comment: Could you make a codepen  please, so i can try to help you :)

Comment: please excuse my nescience, but what is a codepen? sth like plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes plunker or jsfiddle if you prefer

Comment: @Kyrm do you mind if you change a little bit your logic? if it is the case i will give you my directive for checking email avalaibility

Comment: i don't mind at all, if you tell me how exactly I am supposed to change my logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jsFiddle needed some tweaking to work, but in general, what you need to do to make this work is:

- In the mFac.checkUsernameAvailability function you need to *return* the $http.post() result.
- You need to inject $q to the factory.
- Instead of returning res.data, just return res
- In all occurrences in which you return a string, return $q.when(str) (where str is the string). This will make sure all exist paths of your function return a promise (and then you can call then in all cases).

Comment: Why the need to inject $q? I don't use multiple $http requests in the function

Comment: So that you can wrap the strings you return with a promise using $q.when(). I created a working jsFiddle based on yours: https://jsfiddle.net/orendr/bj1cgqxf/

Comment: As I understand it, a factory function MUST return a promise, right? So if it supposed to return a string, the string must be turned into a promise using $q.when(), right?